# Runtime error in database helper due to migrating to null safety in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to migrate my code null safe in dart. I inherited this code base and blindly made a lot of null safe changes which is now breaking my app during runtime.

Where the error is occurring:

```
  static Future<List<Map>> getAllEngagements() async {
    final Database db = await (getDBConnector() as FutureOr<Database>);
    var records = await db.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM engagements');
    return records;
  }
```

runtime error:

```
_CastError (type 'Future<Database?>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<Database>' in type cast)
```

Database Helper Class:

```
class DatabaseHelper {
  static Database? _database;

  static Future<Database?> getDBConnector() async {
    if (_database != null) {
      return _database;
    }

    return await _initDatabase();
  }

  static Future<Database?> _initDatabase() async {
    _database = await openDatabase('engagements.db', version: 1,
        onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
      await db.execute(
          'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS engagements(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT NOT NULL, timeStamp TEXT NOT NULL, acres INTEGER NOT NULL, active INTEGER NOT NULL, orders TEXT NOT NULL);');
    });

    return _database;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is a little confusing because of `FutureOr`, but essentially it's telling you that you're triyng to cast a `Future<Database?>` to a `Future<Database>`. (FYI, `as FutureOr<...>` casts should almost never (if not never) be necessary, so if you think you need to use one, you're probably wrong.) You should be using just:

```dart
    final db = await getDBConnector();
```

This happens because `getDBConnector()` is declared to return a `Future<Database?>`.  I can't tell conclusively from the code you've shown, but it appears that it's not intended to logically return `null`.  If so, you should fix its return type (and similarly, that of `_initDatabase`) to just `Future<Database>` and ensure that all exit paths return a non-`null` value:

```dart
  static Future<Database?> getDBConnector() async {
    final _database = this._database;
    if (_database != null) {
      return _database;
    }

    return await _initDatabase();
  }

  static Future<Database> _initDatabase() async {
    _database = await openDatabase('engagements.db', version: 1,
        onCreate: /* ... */);

    return _database!;
  }
```

The above changes assume that `openDatabase` cannot return `null`.

If `openDatabase` *can* legitimately return `null`, then `getAllEngagements` will need to check if `db` is `null` and return something appropriate (e.g. an empty `List`).